How many of the 16 cells of the grid could contain the black dot?
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

All four L-shapes shown in the diagram are to be placed in the 4 by 4 grid so that all sixteen cells are covered and there is no overlap. Each piece can be rotated or reflected before being placed and the black dot is visible from both sides.

How many of the 16 cells of the grid could contain the black dot?

Attribution: UK Junior Mathematical Challenge 2019

The dot can be placed

 in any of the 16 squares.

Solutions:

 

plus the rotations/reflections of these solutions.

+1 Correct answer, nicely displayed!

@Will.Octagon.Gibson I used virtual online graph paper to make a quick drawing. I have now edited it a little to improve the location of the dots.

I made the images for this question using the Numbers app on my iPad.
